# Why does the session container name have to start with a letter?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

All over our code we're using this line of code:

```
$container = new Container(sha1($this->identity()->getEmail()));
```

Unfortunately, ZF2 only allows container names to start with a letter.  Therefore, for some e-mails, this will fail.  Is there a reason for this restriction and if so, why?  I don't think hashing the e-mail is even necessary, but I'm curious why we can't.

Comment: I assume if you look at the source that the container is actually an object, so in PHP variables (in this case objects) names must begin with a letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session container and storage both extend the `Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject` class which allows entries to be accessed as properties (via magic!).

So, once you have the storage you can do:

```php
$container = new Container('containerName');
$storage = $container->getManager()->getStorage();

$container = $storage->containerName;
```

So, all restrictions that apply to PHP object property names apply to session container names.

Not sure why the same restrictions don't apply to the container keys themselves though.